# Changing android:installLocation from auto to internalOnly can lead to Play Store error 963

Tags: android, google-play, version, updates, android-sdcard

When a user updates an app using Play Store, that had the `android:installLocation="auto"` setting declared in it's manifest before, but has been changed to `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` with the current version, updating to the current version leads to Play Store error `963` if the previous app version was installed on an external sd-card.

The version updates without issues, if the app was previously installed on internal storage.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a method to circumvent the error and still get the new version installed on internal storage?

Internal storage is required for the new version, because it introduces a broadcast receiver for the BOOT_COMPLETED event, which will not be called by android, if the app is installed on external storage.

Comment: I am facing same scenario, what's the expected behavior? System should move the app to internal memory behind the scene?

Comment: That is what I would expect at least and the only option that would work with a broader audience. Unfortunately, it is not what happens.

Comment: Can I ask you what you did in the end? Getting error when updating the app is completely unacceptable.

Comment: I rechecked how I handled this, but there was nothing technical that could be done about it (except changing the `installLocation` back to `auto`, which wasn't an option for me). I explained the change in the update information and told users that had moved their app, that they need to reinstall the app. If you have the time, you could roll-out an update first, that warns users that have installed the app externally, that they need to move the app to their internal storage until a specific date, or they need to reinstall the app when they update after that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like working as expected. I have sent your report on to the relevant team. In general, if you find this sort of error the best way of reporting it is via the support links in the Play console. They can get this sort of issue to the right team very quickly, and collect more useful details, so I'd recommend using them.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind for possible future issues.